# Policy in mathematics teaching

Tags: education-research

Recently I was reading [A Pathway to Equitable Math Instruction Dismantling Racism in Mathematics Instruction](https://equitablemath.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/11/1_STRIDE1.pdf)

And I ended up getting in doubt after reading things like this:

[image]

According to the historical product of mathematics which, as I understand it, focuses on objectivity, comes from white supremacy? From where and how does this really prove to be legitimate? Does mathematics with constructive content and dependent on the above come from white supremacy? I would like more information on the subject.

Comment: The article seems more like a general educational and ethics-based booklet  with little to do with mathematics specifically. Writing an article about racism against minorities when it comes to *mathematics education in particular* seems absurd to me. Mathematics is surely one of the, if not *the* least racist subjects. But maybe I am misunderstanding what the article is saying? And I don’t really understand your question.

Comment: Much of what is at that link looks good to me. But I don't think they were at all clear why they think objectivity is problematic. This is a deep discussion. I ask people answering not to take sides in this. Please answer thoughtfully. Please understand that your answer may be what someone sees later when they are trying to understand the issues involved.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, it *might* be true that mathematics itself is not racist. But there are many problematic things about the way we teach it. The booklet linked is addressed to mathematics teachers, specifically.

Comment: I don't understand the objection to treating matrices as a precalculus topic. Yes, you could each 3rd graders to multiply matrices right after they learn addition and multiplication, but they are not likely to find this knowledge useful. On the other hand, a student who has studied systems of linear equations, especially systems with more than two variables, will understand that matrices are a powerful tool. Algebra II or Precalculus seems to me to be the right place to talk about this. And if a student has missed out on linear systems during Covid, better to re-teach that than matrices.

Comment: @WillOrrick, I think that might mean that lack of knowledge of matrices is being used to keep students out of calculus? And we don't need matrices in calculus. (I took it out of my teaching of precalculus because student said precalc was harder than calc, and I knew that was because we rushed too much.)

Comment: Approaching topics that way may or may not be a good idea, but of course it isn't white supremacist in the way that the term is commonly understood. You have to go to the links in the cited links of this paper, such as: https://www.thc.texas.gov/public/upload/preserve/museums/files/White_Supremacy_Culture.pdf to understand what they mean by this term.

Comment: @SueVanHattum I'm not sure how to square your reading with "even though the only math skill needed as a prerequisite is arithmetic".  It sounds to me that they're claiming that matrices could be taught earlier than they usually are and that the only reason they aren't is that teachers lack "true understanding of prerequisite knowledge". I wasn't advocating that matrices be taught in Algebra II or Precalculus, only that they not be taught before that (unless there's a good reason for doing so).

Comment: Why do you care about this booklet? Unless it is a marching order from your principal, but even then there is so much meaningless language in it that it can be safely ignored. CRT is a hot topic, and edu-consultants try to build a career off it.

Comment: @WillOrrick The point is that we often needlessly gate keep.  Linear algebra is an extremely powerful tool, but most institutions lock it away behind a wall of calculus.  If a student *could* access linear algebra, but systemic inequalities are *needlessly* holding them back (lack of access to excellent pre-calc instruction in high school), this is an equity issue.

Comment: @Behemooth I would recommend reading the work of Rochelle Gutierrez if you are interested in learning more about the intersection between mathematics and social justice.

Comment: @SueVanHattum As Adam mentioned in a comment, the list of characteristics of white supremacy culture are taken from a 2001 workbook by Jones and Okun.  To answer your question about what they regard as problematic about objectivity, the workbook has this to say:

Comment: **Objectivity**
• the belief that there is such a thing as being objective
• the belief that emotions are inherently destructive, irrational, and should not play a role in decision-making or group process
• invalidating people who show emotion
• requiring people to think in a linear fashion and ignoring or invalidating those who think in other ways
• impatience with any thinking that does not appear “logical” to those with power

Comment: **Antidotes:** realize that everybody has a world view and that everybody’s world view affects the way they understand things; realize this means you too; push yourself to sit with discomfort when people are expressing themselves in ways which are not familiar to you; assume that everybody has a valid point and your job is to understand what that point is

Comment: In the context of mathematics education, it seems to me that the objection they have is to the ordering of the curriculum as a linear sequence of topics. This is an example of objectivity because it "require[s] people to think in a linear fashion and ignore[s] or invalidate[s] those who think in other ways".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer. I might not be answering the question asked (it is too unclear for me to be sure), but my answer is to what I think is being addressed in the linked book. (And if this question gets muddied in confusion, I may pose a related question soon.)

How is the teaching of mathematics sullied by racism or white supremacism?

1. The naming of theorems and mathematical objects is eurocentric:  * We speak (in the U.S. and I'm guessing many other countries) of Pascal's Triangle, yet it was invented many times (long before Pascal lived) in India, China, Persia,and others. ([See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).)    * The Pythagorean Theorem was also invented long before Pythagoras, in other cultures. (I know the argument that Pythagoras was the first to prove it. I doubt that that's accurate. We don't know all of what happened in those other cultures. Archeology is not great at getting all of the written records.)
2. Math classes have been used as a filter for decades or centuries, to weed people out of certain professions. Think about doctors, for example. Are they required to do more math than they need? And lawyers, perhaps? So there used to be this mindset that it made sense for lots of students to fail. Who failed? Why? Look at the funding of our K12 systems in the U.S. and you see that economics (and race) are deeply involved. Why is race involved? The best book I know of on this is ***[The Color of Law](https://bookshop.org/books/the-color-of-law-a-forgotten-history-of-how-our-government-segregated-america/9781631494536)***, by Richard Rothstein. [Here's an article](https://www.npr.org/2017/05/03/526655831/a-forgotten-history-of-how-the-u-s-government-segregated-america) about his work. Basically, our education system is funded by property tax, and our country was segregated by laws put in place by the government. Our history is a mess.
3. If we are trying to be anti-racist in our teaching, what can we do? There's a lot, and that book is trying to lay it out. Mathematical facts may be objective in a way we do not find problematic, but the choices of topics to cover in each course is not as objective as that. And stopping students from taking college level courses because of holes in their education has racist effect. If we can do things differently, we must. One solution that's happening in California is for students who are not interested in STEM to take statistics, and if their background is weak, to have co-requisite support. For students interested in STEM, it's a little harder, but I tell my students that it's my job to help them get from where they are to where they want to be. (And their job is to do the work it takes, while I guide them.) I explain misconceptions about fractions to my calculus students.

I will stop here for now. Yes, there are books about this. It will take books and good will, and effort from us all, to change the racist world we are living in.

Comment: Downvoted, because this is not something that will make any difference. Say, some theorems will be renamed, then what? Does celebrating Martin Luther King Jr. day magically did away with racial prejudice and institutionalized racism? Nope. His image and message was appropriated and re-painted. They often quote his words from "I Have a Dream", but not from "Beyond Vietnam".

Comment: @RustyCore Sue's answer is an accurate and well-expressed overview of the arguments in favor of anti-racist math education.  You're free to be opposed to anti-racist math education, but downvoting her answer because of that seems a bit like shooting the messenger.

Comment: @Matthew Daly: I was thinking the same thing (and was going to say so, then I saw your comment), namely that the downvotes (2 as I write this) are likely based on not recognizing the difference between *presenting arguments* others have raised for something and *agreement with those arguments*. Basically, the OP asked what are the arguments, and Sue gave some. Possibly the last sentence gets slightly into agreement/advocacy, but to me the wording there seems a general observation and not advocacy of the arguments previously presented.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134379/discussion-on-answer-by-sue-vanhattum-policy-in-mathematics-teaching).

Comment: (+1) for this statement: **"Mathematical facts may be objective in a way we do not find problematic, but the choices of topics to cover in each course is not as objective as that."**

Comment: Sue's second point reminds me of the Coffin Problems (http://www.tanyakhovanova.com/coffins.html). Just as another example of how math can be used as a way to filter out certain 'unwanted' individuals.

Comment: Thanks for making that connection. There are more subtle ways that similar things happen. In the past, when math was seen as a male activity, male authors writing problems would not have seen any issues in their choice of topics. Female students might have been put off, though, by tools, sailing, sports, etc When we choose story problems without thought, we may be saying who is welcome and who is not.